# FOSUserBundle, PUGX bundle, SQL error after submit

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I've configured PUGXMultiUserBundle as it is shown in documentation, and when I try to register I get an error and to tell the truth I have no idea, where I should search for solution.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS username3,  t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical4, t0.email AS email5, 
t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical6, t0.enabled AS enabled7, t0.salt AS salt8, 
t0.password AS password9, t0.last_login AS last_login10, t0.locked AS locked11, 
t0.expired AS expired12, t0.expires_at AS expires_at13, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token14,
t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at15, t0.roles AS roles16, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired17, 
t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at18, t0.id AS id19, 
t0.type FROM fill_user t0 LEFT JOIN user_one t1 ON t0.id = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN user_two t2 ON t0.id = t2.id WHERE t0.username = ?' with params ["asd"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.type' in 'field list'
```

Comment: The `fill_user` table does not contain a column named `type`. You might need to run `app/console doctrine:schema:update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the final line, it says that the `fill_user` table does not have a `type` column.

You probably didn't update your database schema yet. To do so, run the console tool:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update
```